# sound won’t play on iOS

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, just-audio

I’m building a YouTube downloader and download the media as an audio then i save them on Isar local database, the problem is the audio on the iOS won’t Play it works on Android fine but won’t work on iOS,
I’m using just_audio package

this is the download logic

```
    class AudiosDownloader extends ChangeNotifier {
  late final List<AudioInfo> _downloadedAudios = [];
  late final TextEditingController textFieldController;
  var appDocumentsDir =  getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

  bool _isDownloading = false;
  double _downloadProgress = 0.0;

  List<AudioInfo> get downloadedAudios => _downloadedAudios;

  bool get isDownloading => _isDownloading;

  double get downloadProgress => _downloadProgress;

  

  Future<void> downloadAudios(
      String videoLink, TextEditingController linkController) async {
    try {
      _isDownloading = true;
      _downloadProgress = 0.0;

      notifyListeners();

      // Get the video metadata

      var yt = YoutubeExplode();
      var video = await yt.videos.get(videoLink);

      if (_downloadedAudios.any((audio) => audio.title == video.title)) {
        // Audio already exists, no need to download again
        _isDownloading = false;
        _downloadProgress = 0.0;
        notifyListeners();
        return;
      }

      // Get the video stream to download
      var manifest = await yt.videos.streamsClient.getManifest(video.id.value);
      var streamInfo = manifest.audioOnly.withHighestBitrate();
      var stream = yt.videos.streamsClient.get(streamInfo);

      // Get the app's documents directory to save the video
      final dir =await appDocumentsDir;
      var filePath = '${dir.path}/${video.title}.mp3';
      // Download the video stream and save it to a file
      v

ar fileStream = File(filePath).openWrite();
      var totalBytes = streamInfo.size.totalBytes;
      var receivedBytes = 0;

      stream.listen(
        (data) {
          receivedBytes += data.length;
          var progress = receivedBytes / totalBytes;
          _downloadProgress = progress;
          notifyListeners();
          fileStream.add(data);
        },
        onDone: () async {
          fileStream.close();
          _isDownloading = false;
          _downloadProgress = 0.0;
          var audio = AudioInfo(
            title: video.title,
            artistName: video.author,
            coverImage: video.thumbnails.highResUrl,
            filePath: filePath,
            id: int.parse(video.id.value.replaceAll(RegExp(r'[^0-9]'), '')),
            audioDuration: video.duration?.inSeconds.toDouble(),
          );
          IsarProvider().saveData(audio);

          if (kDebugMode) {
            print(audio.filePath);
          }
          notifyListeners();
        },
        onError: (e) {
          fileStream.close();
          _isDownloading = false;
          _downloadProgress = 0.0;
          notifyListeners();
          throw e;
        },
        cancelOnError: true,
      );
    } catch (e) {
      _isDownloading = false;
      _downloadProgress = 0.0;
      notifyListeners();
      rethrow;
    }
  }

  

  @override
  notifyListeners();
}
```

and this is the class that i handle the saving to the database

```
    class IsarProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  late Future<Isar> db;

  IsarProvider() {
    db = openDB();
  }

  Future<Isar> openDB() async {
    if (Isar.instanceNames.isEmpty) {
      final appDir =await  getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

      return await Isar.open(
        [AudioInfoSchema],
        directory: appDir.path,
      );

    }
    return await Future.value(Isar.getInstance());
  }

  Future<void> saveData(AudioInfo audio) async {
    final isar = await db;
    await isar.writeTxn<int>(() async {
      isar.audioInfos.put(audio);
      AudiosDownloader().downloadedAudios.add(audio);
      return 0;
    });
  }

  Future<List<AudioInfo>> fetchDownloadedAudiosFromDatabase() async {
    final isar = await db;

    final audioInfos = await isar.audioInfos.where().findAll();
    return audioInfos
        .map((audioInfo) => AudioInfo(
              id: audioInfo.id,
              title: audioInfo.title,
              artistName: audioInfo.artistName,
              coverImage: audioInfo.coverImage,
              filePath: audioInfo.filePath,
              audioDuration: audioInfo.audioDuration,
            ))
        .toList();
  }

  Future<void> deleteVideo(int index) async {
    final isar = await db;
    final appDir =await  getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    late List<AudioInfo> downloadedAudios = AudiosDownloader().downloadedAudios;
    final file = File('${appDir.path}/${downloadedAudios[index].title}.mp3');
    if (await file.exists()) {
      await file.delete();

    }
    final d = downloadedAudios.removeAt(index);
    await isar.writeTxn<int>(() async {
      await isar.audioInfos.delete(d.id);

      return 0;
    });
    downloadedAudios = await isar.audioInfos.where().findAll();

    notifyListeners();
  }


  @override
  notifyListeners();
}
```

and this is the UI page that i display the audios and play it by tapping on one

```
    class PlaylistPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const PlaylistPage({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<PlaylistPage> createState() => _PlaylistPageState();
}

class _PlaylistPageState extends State<PlaylistPage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  final _player = AudioPlayer();
  int _currentIndex = -1;
  bool _isPlaying = false;
  bool showContainer = true;

  // define an animation controller for rotate the song cover image
  late AnimationController _animationController;
  late Future<PaletteGenerator> _futurePaletteGenerator;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _animationController =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: const Duration(seconds: 3));

    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      final downloader = Provider.of<AudiosDownloader>(context, listen: false);
      final fetchingData = Provider.of<IsarProvider>(context, listen: false);
      if (downloader.downloadedAudios.isEmpty) {
        fetchingData.fetchDownloadedAudiosFromDatabase().then((audioInfos) {
          setState(() {
            downloader.downloadedAudios.addAll(audioInfos);
          });
        });
      }
    });

    _player.playbackEventStream.listen((event) {
      if (event.processingState == ProcessingState.completed) {
        setState(() {
          _isPlaying = false;
        });
      }
    });
  }

  void _play(int index, AudiosDownloader downloader,
      Function(bool) updatedIsPlaying) async {
    if (_currentIndex == index) {
      if (_isPlaying == false) {
        await _player.play();
        setState(() {
          _isPlaying = true;
          showContainer = true;
        });
      } else {
        await _player.pause();
        setState(() {
          _isPlaying = false;
          showContainer = true;
        });
      }
    } else {
      final audioInfo = downloader.downloadedAudios[index];
      final audioFile = File(audioInfo.filePath);

      if (await audioFile.exists()) {
        await _player.setFilePath(audioFile.path);
        await _player.play();
        setState(() {
          _currentIndex = index;
          _isPlaying = true;
          showContainer = true;
        });


      } else {
        if (kDebugMode) {
          print("Audio file does not exist.");
          print(audioInfo.filePath);
          print(audioFile.existsSync());
        }
      }
    }
    updatedIsPlaying(_isPlaying);
  }

void _stop(int index, AudiosDownloader downloader,
      Function(bool) updatedIsPlaying) async {
    await _player.stop();
    setState(() {
      _currentIndex = index;
      _isPlaying = false;
      showContainer = false;
    });
    updatedIsPlaying(_isPlaying);
  }

  var appDocumentsDir = getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<AudiosDownloader>(builder: (context, downloader, _) {
      return Stack(children: [
        downloader.downloadedAudios.isEmpty
            ? const Center(
                child: Text('No downloaded data'),
              )
            : ListView.separated(
                separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return const Divider(
                    color: Colors.white30,
                    height: 0,
                    thickness: 1,
                    indent: 85,
                  );
                },
                itemCount: downloader.downloadedAudios.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  final audioI = downloader.downloadedAudios[index];

                  return Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                    child: Dismissible(
                      key: Key(audioI.filePath),
                      onDismissed: (direction) async {
                        await Provider.of<IsarProvider>(context, listen: false)
                            .deleteVideo(index);

                        if (index >= 1) {
                          setState(() {
                            downloader.downloadedAudios.removeAt(index);
                          });
                        }
                      },
                      background: Container(
                        color: Colors.red,
                        alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20),
                        child: const Icon(
                          Icons.delete,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: ListTile(
                        title: Text(
                          audioI.title,
                          style: const TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        ),
                        subtitle: Text(
                          audioI.artistName,
                          style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white70),
                        ),
                        leading: ClipRRect(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                          child: Image.network(audioI.coverImage),
                        ),
                        onTap: () async {
                          PermissionStatus micState =
                              await Permission.microphone.request();

                          if (micState == PermissionStatus.granted) {
                            _play(index, downloader, (isPlaying) {
                              if (kDebugMode) {
                                print(_player.playerState);
                                print(audioI.filePath);
                                print(audioI.audioDuration);
                              }
                            });
                          }
                          if (micState == PermissionStatus.denied) {
                            showAlertDialog(
                              context,
                              'Permission Denied',
                              'Allow access the mic',
                              'Cancel',
                              'Settings',
                              () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
                              () => openAppSettings(),
                            );
                          }
                          if (micState == PermissionStatus.permanentlyDenied) {
                            showAlertDialog(
                              context,
                              'Permission Disabled',
                              'pleas allow access the mic to play your audios',
                              'Cancel',
                              'Settings',
                              () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
                              () => openAppSettings(),
                            );
                          }
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
        !showContainer
            ? const SizedBox.shrink()
            : FutureBuilder<PaletteGenerator>(
                future: getImageColors(downloader, _currentIndex),
                builder: (
                  context,
                  snapshot,
                ) {
                  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done &&
                      snapshot.hasData &&
                      _currentIndex >= 0 &&
                      _currentIndex < downloader.downloadedAudios.length) {
                    final audioI = downloader.downloadedAudios[_currentIndex];
                    return Positioned(
                      bottom: 0,
                      left: 0,
                      right: 0,
                      child: Container(
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            horizontal: 15, vertical: 50),
                        height: 75,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            gradient: LinearGradient(
                                begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                                end: const Alignment(0, 5),
                                colors: [
                                  snapshot.data?.lightMutedColor?.color ??
                                      Colors.grey,
                                  snapshot.data?.mutedColor?.color ??
                                      Colors.grey,
                                ]),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            AnimatedBuilder(
// // rotate the song cover image
                              animation: _animationController,
                              builder: (_, child) {
// if song is not playing
                                if (!_isPlaying) {
                                  _animationController.stop();
                                } else {
                                  _animationController.forward();
                                  _animationController.repeat();
                                  if (kDebugMode) {}
                                }
                                return Transform.rotate(
                                    angle: _animationController.value *
                                        2 *
                                        math.pi,
                                    child: child);
                              },
                              child: InkWell(
                                onTap: () => Navigator.push(
                                    context,
                                    CupertinoPageRoute(
                                        fullscreenDialog: true,
                                        builder: (context) => PlayerPage(
                                              player: _player,
                                              looping: false,
                                              title: audioI.title,
                                              artistName: audioI.artistName,
                                              coverImage: audioI.coverImage,
                                              currentI: _currentIndex,
                                              audioD: audioI.audioDuration,
                                              path: audioI.filePath,
                                            ))),
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                  child: CircleAvatar(
                                      radius: 30,
                                      backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                                      backgroundImage:
                                          NetworkImage(audioI.coverImage)),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Expanded(
                              child: Column(
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: [
                                  Text(
                                    audioI.title,
                                    maxLines: 2,
                                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                    style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                                  ),
                                  Text(
                                    audioI.artistName,
                                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                    style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                            IconButton(
                              icon: Icon(
                                !_isPlaying ? Icons.play_arrow : Icons.pause,
                                size: 30,
                              ),
                              onPressed: () async {
                                _play(_currentIndex, downloader, (isPlaying) {
                                  if(mounted){
                                    return;
                                  }
                                  if (kDebugMode) {
                                    print(_player.playerState);
                                    print(isPlaying);
                                    print(_player.audioSource);
                                  }
                                });
                              },
                            ),
                            IconButton(
                              icon: const Icon(
                                Icons.stop,
                                size: 30,
                              ),
                              onPressed: () async {
                                _stop(_currentIndex, downloader, (isPlaying) {
                                  if (kDebugMode) {
                                    print(isPlaying);
                                  }
                                });
                              },
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  } else {
                    return const SizedBox.shrink();
                  }
                },
              ),
      ]);
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    if (_animationController.isAnimating) {
      _animationController.stop();
    }
    _player.dispose();
    _player.stop();
    _animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  dynamic showAlertDialog(
      dynamic context,
      String title,
      String content,
      String text1,
      String text2,
      dynamic Function() onPressed1,
      dynamic Function() onPressed2) {
    showCupertinoDialog(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: false,
      builder: (BuildContext context) => CupertinoAlertDialog(
        title: Text(title),
        content: Text(content),
        actions: <CupertinoDialogAction>[
          CupertinoDialogAction(
            onPressed: onPressed1,
            child: Text(text1),
          ),
          CupertinoDialogAction(
            onPressed: onPressed2,
            child: Text(text2),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

i have added the permissions on the info.plist and the pod.file to access the mic and internet and every permission related to playing audio but not working